# Checking if e-mail address is already used

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I'm coding a registration system on php. I'm trying to make it impossible to create two accounts with same e-mail address. I wrote a code which should check it, but it doesn't work. I can create as many accounts as I want with the same e-mail. What's wrong with it?

```
$sqlemail = "SELECT count(*) FROM 'users' WHERE email = ?"; 
$result = $connection->prepare($sqlemail); 
$result->execute($email); 
$emailused = $result->fetch();

if ($emailused!=false) {
    echo 'An account with this e-mail address already exists!';
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($emailused)` to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: I don't see you actually killing the script or anything, just echoing a warning.

Comment: Are you using PDO or MySQLi?  Because you are passing the wrong parameters to `->execute()`.  If you are using PDO, you need to send an array.  If MySQLi, then `->execute()` doesn't want any parameters, you'd need to use `->bind_param()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `email` field a unique key for the table. Then, if you try to insert a duplicate, mysql will throw an error.

You can then handle the error, and display your friendlier message. You can check for the error with [`$result->errorCode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php).

This also keeps you from having to make a `SELECT` before an `INSERT`.

Comment: I used the same technique to check username also. How can I determine is it e-mail or username which is already used? The error code is always the same. Do I have to make two queries?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that in this way. The MySQL error messsage only gives the following: `Message: Can't write; duplicate key in table '%s'`. Which only specifies the table name, not the column. Why not use the email address as the username?

Comment: The usernames will be shown to everybody so it may not be email.

Comment: @Kestis Are you sure the usernames need to be unique as well? For example, on this site, the usernames are not unique. Login username != display username.

Comment: One option would be to move the usernames and emails to their own table. You'd reference the username or email with an id in the user table. Then, the mysql error would return the table where the duplicate key exists. This is also a higher `normal form`.

Comment: It works now! It first enters the email. Then it checks error code. If there is no error it updates the table and inserts the username. Otherwise it deletes the email already inserted.

Comment: @Kestis That sounds like two queries are being made: `INSERT` followed by `UPDATE`. That is one way to handle it, but you could factor it into a single query by doing my last suggestion. Perhaps, it's not that big of a deal for you at this stage. Good job getting it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, use backticks in `users` not `'`

```
 $sqlemail = "SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE email = ?"; 

if ($emailused>0) {
    echo 'An account with this e-mail address already exists!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the email came back with multiple results, the script will execute because you are not killing the script! You need to use `exit;` or `die()` to stop them from progressing, or a re-direct or something.

```
if ($emailused>0) {
    echo 'An account with this e-mail address already exists!';
    exit;
}
```